# Batch duplicate one to multiple files with specific file name at once

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a question copy files with batch at windows machine.

For example, I have a file named `ja.html` and duplicate the file to many files with certain file names following:

`en.html`
`zh-ch.html`,
`ko.html`,
`id.html`

in same directory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for %%a in (en zh-ch ko id) do copy ja.html %%a.html`

Comment: will try that. thanx!!